# Why Spring Data Envers Revision Type returned UNKOWN?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

What i trying to achieve is the revision type that print out UNKNOWN in the response, but in the database exist the revtype. Here is the response :

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "delegate": {
      "id": 1,
      "timestamp": 1594199577086,
      "revisionDate": "2020-07-08T09:12:57.086+0000"
    },
    "revisionNumber": 1,
    "revisionDate": "2020-07-08T16:12:57.086",
    "revisionInstant": "2020-07-08T09:12:57.086Z",
    "revisionType": "UNKNOWN",
    "requiredRevisionInstant": "2020-07-08T09:12:57.086Z",
    "requiredRevisionNumber": 1
  },
  "entity": {
    "id": 2,
    "roleCode": "ROLE001",
    "roleName": "Admin",
    "isInternal": false,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "createdDate": "2020-07-08T09:12:56.723+0000",
    "modifiedDate": "2020-07-08T09:12:56.723+0000",
    "createdBy": "someone",
    "modifiedBy": null,
    "roleDt": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "moduleName": "SALES",
        "permission": "ALL"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "moduleName": "Report",
        "permission": "ALL"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "moduleName": "Dashboard",
        "permission": "ALL"
      }
    ]
  },
  "revisionNumber": 1,
  "requiredRevisionInstant": "2020-07-08T09:12:57.086Z",
  "requiredRevisionNumber": 1,
  "revisionInstant": "2020-07-08T09:12:57.086Z"
}
```

at first i develop with Spring Data Envers, i have the revision type printed out INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, i don't relize when the revision type become UNKNOWN.
Here is my model :
RoleHd.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(of = {"id"})
@Table(name= "msRoleHd")
public class RoleHd {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @NotBlank
    public String roleCode;

    @NotBlank
    public String roleName;

    @NotNull
    public Boolean isInternal;

    public Boolean isDeleted = false;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedDate;
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roleHd", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<RoleDt> roleDt;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "roleHd", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<UserPartnerRole> userPartnerRole;
}
```

RoleDt.java :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name= "msRoleDt")
public class RoleDt {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public String moduleName;

    public String permission;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleId")
    public RoleHd roleHd;

}
```

and here is how i save the data RoleHdService.java :

```
public RoleHd save(InputRequest<RoleHd> request) {
    String currentUser = request.getLoggedInUser();
    RoleHd roleHd = request.getObject();

    if(roleHdRepository.findByroleCodeIgnoreCase(roleHd.getRoleCode()).isPresent()){
        throw new ResourceAlreadyExistException("Role Code "+ roleHd.getRoleCode() +" already exists!");
    }
    
    roleHd.setCreatedBy(currentUser);
    roleHd.getRoleDt().forEach(d -> d.setRoleHd(roleHd));

    return roleHdRepository.save(roleHd);
}
```

here is how i get my revision data from envers :

```
public Revision<Integer, RoleHd> findByIdLatest(Long id) {

    return roleHdRepository.findLastChangeRevision(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFound("Role "+ id +" not found!"));
}
```

here is my application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class B2bApiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(B2bApiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

what did i do wrong until the revisionType printed unknown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, that's a bug from Spring Data Envers, which is i found in this issue :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/issues/215

and it solved in version above 2.2.5 i guess, my project was using 2.2.5 version of spring data envers and my spring boot version was 2.2.5 and then i just update my spring boot project version to 2.3.1 and the others dependency was following and the revisionType is printed now

but i found it broke my javax.validation tags in my entire model, i will start another question for this