# Unable to retrieve the revision number for an entity with spring-data-envers findLastChangeRevision

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

Am trying to get the revision number using the `findLastChangeRevision` method in spring-data-envers. Am able to fetch the last entity but the revision is always`UNKNOWN`. And the revision number and timestamp are empty and `null` respectively always.

Tried debugging with getting all revisions found that all the revisions are `UNKNOWN` and their revision number and timestamp are same as empty and `null` respectively.

Below is my `AuditRevisionListener` have the field annotated with `@RevisionNumber` and `@RevisionTimeStamp`

```
 @RevisionEntity(AuditRevisionListener.class)
 public class AuditRevisionEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "revision_info_id_generator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "revision_info_id_generator",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "revision_info_id_seq"),
                    @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                    @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
            })
    @RevisionNumber
    private Long revisionId;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    private long timestamp;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer userId;

}
```

The version of spring-boot is 2.6.2

Referred this already and is a bit different to the above context. Could this be a bug?

[spring-data-envers revisionType UNKNOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62791547/why-spring-data-envers-revision-type-returned-unkown)

I understand the solution can be obtained using hibernate-envers, but looking into using tspring-data-envers

Thanks

Comment: The spring-boot version is 2.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate may proxify your `AuditRevisionEntity` when Spring-Data in its turn will try to use reflection to get the values of revision id and a timestamp. The problem is that the proxy object hides this values until you use getter method.
Adding `@Proxy(lazy = false)` annotation on your revision entity might help.

See this issue for reference:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-envers/issues/250